# How to delete all rows with counterparts and the counterparts themselves?

Tags: r, for-loop

Please, have a look at the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, -2, -1, 3, 2 , 2),
                 col2 = c("a", "b", "a", "c", "b", "b"),
                 col3 = c("d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"))
```

My goal is to delete all rows in `df` with negative counterparts and the counterparts themselves. Now, what do I mean by a "negative counterpart"? A row has a negative counterpart if there is another row with the same number in `col1` but with a minus, and the same value in `col2`. The value in `col3` does not matter. Rows can have multiple counterparts. In this case, only one of them should be deleted. Thus, in the above example, the final data frame should contain only the fourth and either the fifth or sixth row.

The real `df` has approx. 4*10^5 rows and 25 columns. Most rows do not have a counterpart. So, my idea was to build a for loop that checks for each row whose value in `col1` is less than 0, if there is positive counterpart. But I am struggling with the "checking" part.

```
for (i in nrow(df)) {
  if (df[i, ] < 0) {
  # check for positive counterparts here
  }   
}
```

Comment: If `col1` were negative in the fourth row, would you keep it ?

Comment: @Steven Yes, I would.

Comment: And... would you be inclined to also keep either row 2, 5 or 6 or only 5 or 6 ?

Comment: @Steven That is a good remark. Positive rows are to be preferred over negative ones. So, in the above `df`, keep either row 5 or 6.

Comment: And what if you have many identical entries (in col1, col2) with no negative counterparts ? Do you keep them all .. or only one ?

Comment: As long as a row has no negative counterpart, it is kept.